# utilizo useSelector con redux y obtengo data desfazada en mi formulario

Tags: reactjs, formularios, redux

Estoy haciendo un ejercico para aprender, un simple CRUD tomando datos de endpoints simulados con json-server.
Estoy en la parte de modificar, para ellos uitlizo el siguiente custom hook:

```
import { useState } from "react"

export const useForm = (initialState = {}) => {

    const [values, setValues] = useState(initialState)

    const reset = () => {
        setValues(initialState)
    }

    const handleInputChange = ({ target }) => {

        setValues({
            ...values,
            [target.name]: target.value
        })


    }

    return [values, handleInputChange, reset]
```

y este es mi componente UpdateItem.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React from 'react'

import { useForm } from '../hooks/useForm'
import { baseURL } from '../configuration/baseURL'

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { types } from '../types/types';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

import Swal from 'sweetalert2'


export default function UpdateItem() {

    const history = useHistory()

    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const { selected } = useSelector(state => state.axiosDataReducer)
    const { data } = useSelector(state => state.axiosDataReducer)

    const id = selected?.id

    const selectedItemtoModify = data?.filter(x => x?.id === id)
    console.log(data !== undefined && selectedItemtoModify)

    console.log(selectedItemtoModify[0]?.name)
    console.log(selectedItemtoModify[0]?.cost)
    console.log(selectedItemtoModify[0]?.department[0].name)
    console.log(selectedItemtoModify[0]?.department[0].identification)
    console.log(selectedItemtoModify[0]?.category[0].name)
    console.log(selectedItemtoModify[0]?.category[0].id)

    const name = selectedItemtoModify[0]?.name
    const cost = selectedItemtoModify[0]?.cost
    const departmentName = selectedItemtoModify[0]?.department[0].name
    const departmentIdentification = selectedItemtoModify[0]?.department[0].identification
    const categoryName = selectedItemtoModify[0]?.category[0].name
    const categoryId = selectedItemtoModify[0]?.category[0].id


    const [formValues, handleInputChange] = useForm({

        newName: name,
        newCost: cost,
        newDepartmentName: departmentName,
        newDepartmentIdentification: departmentIdentification,
        newCategoryName: categoryName,
        newCategoryId: categoryId
    })

    const {
        newName,
        newCost,
        newDepartmentName,
        newDepartmentIdentification,
        newCategoryName,
        newCategoryId } = formValues

    const handleUpdateItem = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        try {
            await axios.put(`${baseURL}${id}`, {
                "id": +id,
                "name": newName,
                "cost": +newCost,
                "department": [
                    {
                        "name": newDepartmentName,
                        "identification": newDepartmentIdentification
                    }
                ],
                "category": [
                    {
                        "name": newCategoryName,
                        "id": +newCategoryId
                    }
                ]
            })
            const modified = await axios.get(`${baseURL}${id}`)
            const { data } = modified

            dispatch({
                type: types.modify,
                modifiedItem: data
            });
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'success',
                title: 'Your item has been modified',
                showConfirmButton: false,
                timer: 1500
            })
            setTimeout(() => {
                history.push('/')
            }, 1500);

        } catch (error) {
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: 'Oops...',
                text: 'Something went wrong!',
                footer: 'Unable to modify item, who passes the id?'
            })
            return dispatch({
                type: types.error,
                msg: 'Unable to modify item'
            })
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className='container mb-5 pb-3 bg-light'>
            <form className='mt-3' onSubmit={handleUpdateItem}>

                <input
                    className='input mb-1 p-3'
                    type='text'
                    title='Name'
                    placeholder='Name'
                    name='newName'
                    autoComplete='off'
                    value={newName}
                    onChange={handleInputChange} />
                <input
                    className='input mb-1 p-3'
                    type='text'
                    title='Cost'
                    placeholder='Cost'
                    name='newCost'
                    autoComplete='off'
                    value={newCost}
                    onChange={handleInputChange} />
                <input
                    className='input mb-1 p-3'
                    type='text'
                    title='Department Name'
                    placeholder='Department Name'
                    name='newDepartmentName'
                    autoComplete='off'
                    value={newDepartmentName}
                    onChange={handleInputChange} />
                <input
                    className='input mb-1 p-3'
                    type='text'
                    title='Department Identification'
                    placeholder='Department Identification'
                    name='newDepartmentIdentification'
                    autoComplete='off'
                    value={newDepartmentIdentification}
                    onChange={handleInputChange} />
                <input
                    className='input mb-1 p-3'
                    type='text'
                    title='Category Name'
                    placeholder='Category Name'
                    name='newCategoryName'
                    autoComplete='off'
                    value={newCategoryName}
                    onChange={handleInputChange} />
                <input
                    className='input mb-1 p-3'
                    type='text'
                    title='Category Id'
                    placeholder='Category Id'
                    name='newCategoryId'
                    autoComplete='off'
                    value={newCategoryId}
                    onChange={handleInputChange} />

                <button className='btn btn-success ' type=' submit'>
                    Modify Item
                </button>
```

y este es es reducer:

```
import { types } from "../types/types";

const initialState = {
    data: null,
    selected: null,
    deleted: '',
    created: null,
    modified: null,
    error: ''
}

export const axiosDataReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.get:
            return {
                ...state,
                data: action.data
            }
        case types.selected:
            return {
                ...state,
                selected: action.selectedItem
            }
        case types.delete:
            return {
                ...state,
                data: state.data.filter(item => item.id !== action.deletedItem.id),
                deleted: action.deletedItem
            }
        case types.created:
            return {
                ...state,
                created: action.createdItem
            }
        case types.modified:
            return {
                ...state,
                modified: action.modifiedItem
            }

        case types.error:
            return {
                ...state,
                error: action.msg
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

todo funciona correcto PERO, cuando selecciono un item de la table el valor que muestra inicialmente son las celdas vacias. Peor funciona bien si edito su contenido, se edita correctamente (sin poder ver cuales eran lso valores iniciales, pues aparece en blanco).
Y cuando voy a la tabla y selecciono OTRO nuevo valor se muestra el formulario PERO con el valor seleccionado anteriormente, aunque en los console.log se muestran correctamente los valores correctos, se podria decir que lso valores que muestra el formulario estan desfazados, y n ose si es fruto de que al principio cuando se obtiene la data con el useSelector primero es undefined y despues es que la obtiene en otro render?

algo asi:

undefined

undefined

undefined

y despues obtiene la data correctamente

valor1
valor2
valor3

pero el formulario solo se actualiza con los undefined? (nada) en vez de actualizarse con lso otros valores

Comment: Se supone que el `estado` debe manejarse con `redux`, pero parece que el `estado` en `useForm` no se esta manejando con `redux`. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Lo que hice fue dividir la logica del componente UpdateItem.js en dos
uan encargada de obtener la data de la store con useSelector (selected) y a su vez se encarga de renderizar el otro componente encargado de los formularios solo si (selected!==null)

quedando conformado de esta forma:

UpdateItem.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React from 'react'

import { useForm } from '../hooks/useForm'
import { baseURL } from '../configuration/baseURL'

import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { types } from '../types/types';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

import Swal from 'sweetalert2'


export default function UpdateItem({ id, name, cost, departmentName, departmentIdentification, categoryName, categoryId }) {

    const history = useHistory()

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const [formValues, handleInputChange, reset] = useForm({

        newName: name,
        newCost: cost,
        newDepartmentName: departmentName,
        newDepartmentIdentification: departmentIdentification,
        newCategoryName: categoryName,
        newCategoryId: categoryId
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        reset()
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [id])

    const {
        newName,
        newCost,
        newDepartmentName,
        newDepartmentIdentification,
        newCategoryName,
        newCategoryId } = formValues

    const handleUpdateItem = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        try {
            await axios.put(`${baseURL}${id}`, {
                "id": +id,
                "name": newName,
                "cost": +newCost,
                "department": [
                    {
                        "name": newDepartmentName,
                        "identification": newDepartmentIdentification
                    }
                ],
                "category": [
                    {
                        "name": newCategoryName,
                        "id": +newCategoryId
                    }
                ]
            })
            const modified = await axios.get(`${baseURL}${id}`)
            const { selected } = modified

            dispatch({
                type: types.modify,
                modifiedItem: selected
            });
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'success',
                title: 'Your item has been modified',
                showConfirmButton: false,
                timer: 1500
            })
            setTimeout(() => {
                history.push('/')
            }, 1500);

        } catch (error) {
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: 'Oops...',
                text: 'Something went wrong!',
                footer: 'Unable to modify item, who passes the id?'
            })
            return dispatch({
                type: types.error,
                msg: 'Unable to modify item'
            })
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className='container mt-5 mb-5 pb-3 bg-light'>
            <form className='mt-3' onSubmit={handleUpdateItem}>

                <input
                    className='input mb-1 p-3'
                    type='text'
                    title='Name'
                    placeholder='Name'
                    name='newName'
                    autoComplete='off'
                    value={newName}
                    onChange={handleInputChange} />
                <input
                    className='input mb-1 p-3'
                    type='text'
                    title='Cost'
                    placeholder='Cost'
                    name='newCost'
                    autoComplete='off'
                    value={newCost}
                    onChange={handleInputChange} />
                <input
                    className='input mb-1 p-3'
                    type='text'
                    title='Department Name'
                    placeholder='Department Name'
                    name='newDepartmentName'
                    autoComplete='off'
                    value={newDepartmentName}
                    onChange={handleInputChange} />
                <input
                    className='input mb-1 p-3'
                    type='text'
                    title='Department Identification'
                    placeholder='Department Identification'
                    name='newDepartmentIdentification'
                    autoComplete='off'
                    value={newDepartmentIdentification}
                    onChange={handleInputChange} />
                <input
                    className='input mb-1 p-3'
                    type='text'
                    title='Category Name'
                    placeholder='Category Name'
                    name='newCategoryName'
                    autoComplete='off'
                    value={newCategoryName}
                    onChange={handleInputChange} />
                <input
                    className='input mb-1 p-3'
                    type='text'
                    title='Category Id'
                    placeholder='Category Id'
                    name='newCategoryId'
                    autoComplete='off'
                    value={newCategoryId}
                    onChange={handleInputChange} />

                <button className='btn btn-success ' type=' submit'>
                    Modify Item
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

y asi

ConditionalRenderUpdateItem.js

```
import React from 'react'

import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import UpdateItem from '../screen/UpdateItem';


export default function ConditionalRenderUpdateItem() {

    const { selected } = useSelector(state => state.axiosDataReducer)

    console.log(selected)

    console.log(selected?.name)
    console.log(selected?.cost)
    console.log(selected?.department[0].name)
    console.log(selected?.department[0].identification)
    console.log(selected?.category[0].name)
    console.log(selected?.category[0].id)

    const id = selected?.id
    const name = selected?.name
    const cost = selected?.cost
    const departmentName = selected?.department[0].name
    const departmentIdentification = selected?.department[0].identification
    const categoryName = selected?.category[0].name
    const categoryId = selected?.category[0].id
    return (
        <div>
            {(selected !== null) &&
                <UpdateItem
                    id={id}
                    name={name}
                    cost={cost}
                    departmentName={departmentName}
                    departmentIdentification={departmentIdentification}
                    categoryName={categoryName}
                    categoryId={categoryId}
                />}
        </div>
    )
}
```

de esta forma se obtiene adecuadamente

PS: otra referencia a esta solucion esta en este link que dejo:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68978284/out-of-phase-data-in-form-value-using-useselector

Tambien voy a mostrar el useForm, para que se vea en todo detalle, el cual es el empleado pro el profesor Fernando Herrera en su curso de React de UdemyÑ

useForm

```
import { useState } from "react"

export const useForm = (initialState = {}) => {

    const [values, setValues] = useState(initialState)

    const reset = () => {
        setValues(initialState)
    }

    const handleInputChange = ({ target }) => {

        setValues({
            ...values,
            [target.name]: target.value
        })


    }

    return [values, handleInputChange, reset]
}
```

Comment: Sin embargo, se sigue obteniendo el mismo error. Aunque se obtien correctamente el primer valor, sigue sucediendo el mismo desfasaje pues se muestra en el form el valor anterior anque selecciones uno nuevo. Para solucionarlo añadí el parametro reset del custom hook useForm y utilice un useEffect...que voy a  poner en la edición de la pregunta...